How can I change the looks of Noice.nvim elements?
I went through the documentation and it doesn't seem very clear. For instance, I want to try remove the "cmdline" title in the command box.

I looked at the views section and it seems like the element is cmdline_popup, and in the views.lua file linked below the table, it specifies this under cmdline_popup = {:
    win_options = {
      winhighlight = {
        Normal = "NoiceCmdlinePopup",
        FloatTitle = "NoiceCmdlinePopupTitle",
        FloatBorder = "NoiceCmdlinePopupBorder",
        IncSearch = "",
        CurSearch = "",
        Search = "",
      },

I wrote this in my init.lua but it doesn't work. Perhaps I interpreted the documentation wrong or am missing something.
require("noice").setup({
  views = {
    cmdline_popup = {
      win_options = {
        winhighlight = {
          FloatTitle = "",
          FloatBorder = ""
        },
      }
    }
  }
})

